# GitHub Authentication - How to limit to the organization users?

Tags: authentication, github, github-api, github-app

I have a GitHub app setup for authentication for my webapp per https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/basics-of-authentication/.  How can I setup my GitHub app so that only members of the organization can authenticate?

Thanks

Comment: have you read that: https://help.github.com/en/articles/enabling-oauth-app-access-restrictions-for-your-organization ?

Comment: yes, that doesn't limit who can authenticate via the app.  only who can use it (which seems odd).

Comment: Did you tried to use ssh authentication-tokens?

Comment: If they are providing access tokens via oauth web flow, you can query whether they are a member of your Organization. If not, you can ignore them via server side logic.

Comment: Though re-reading the OP. You may want to transfer ownership of the App to your organization and restrict the visibility to just the user/org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's no way to do this directly.  You need to query if the user is a member of an authorized org.  Seems odd to be but thats the way this is handled in every implementation i've seen